# right way to mount sdcard in linux

Tags: mount, usb, sd-card

i have a problem with mounting my camcoder with sdcard as volume. It seems it is sdcard problem, can it be repaired? I have reformated sdcard in windows system but this did'nt solve problem all remained the same.

```
#lsubs:Bus 001 Device 011: ID 0603:8611 Novatek Microelectronics Corp.   
# lsblk
NAME                        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT

sdb                           8:16   1  29.8G  0 disk 
└─sdb1                        8:17   1  29.8G  0 part 
sr0                          11:0    1  1024M  0 rom  
# mount /dev/sdb /mountpoint
mount: /dev/sdb: can't read superblock
    #dmesg:
[  393.331415] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  393.331428] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  393.331443] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 02 00 00 02 00
[  393.331470] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 2
[  393.331497] EXT4-fs (sdb): unable to read superblock
[  393.338515] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[  393.338525] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  393.338538] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  393.338551] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  393.338565] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 40 00 00 02 00
[  393.338593] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 64
[  393.338621] isofs_fill_super: bread failed, dev=sdb, iso_blknum=16, block=32
[  393.346514] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Unhandled sense code
[  393.346524] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_SENSE
[  393.346537] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Sense Key : Medium Error [current] 
[  393.346550] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb]  Add. Sense: Unrecovered read error
[  393.346564] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] CDB: Read(10): 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 01 00
[  393.346592] end_request: critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0
[  393.346619] FAT-fs (sdb): unable to read boot sector
```

Answer (score 1):

Medium error means inability to get raw sector data - it's on lower layer than file systems or even disk partitioning. If Windows works with this card but Linux doesn't, it means that Linux incorrectly detects needed protocol to access it. It's rather often that device misreports needed protocol so special quirk table is used to fix reported data. You should ask Linux kernel hacker to help with such problems (so this answer definitely isn't final).